# Type mismatch : Trim and Split in same line and use of array

Tags: arrays, excel, declaration, vba

```
Sub matchid()
Dim Coun, anncount, dcoun, danncount, i, j, Tcount As Integer
Dim orange As Range
Dim Name, dName As String
Dim SNmae(), dNmae() As String
Dim osheet As Worksheet
For Coun = 2 To 157
Set osheet = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set orange = osheet.Range("H" & Coun)
If WorksheetFunction.IsNA(orange) Then
Name = osheet.Range("G" & Coun).Value
SNmae = Trim(Split(Name, " "))
```

In the code above, I have declared an array and tried to put values by splitting a string with space and trimming the same. In the line I does this gives me a Type mismatch error.
Have I declared the array wrong? Should I "set" the array values?

Comment: You can't pass an array to `Trim`. Given that you are splitting on spaces, I assume you should be using `Trim` first: `SNmae = Split(Trim(Name), " ")`

Comment: Thanks,
I need to trim after splitting with space. Would that be incorrect technically?
Say like "asha  gamage" needs to be "asha" and "gamage". There's two space between these two strings.

Comment: There's no point to that. Splitting on spaces will remove all spaces from the data anyway, but it will give you empty array elements. You could work around that using: `SNmae = Split(Application.Trim(Name), " ")`

Comment: Thanks a lot for this information.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is with Array Declaration part.

Try below. Hope should work.

```
 Dim SNmae() As String
 Dim dNmae() As String
```